# Gulpfile.js request

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-sass

i'm trying to run a gulpfile with autoprefixer, sass and livereload. I spent all evening but I couldn't run them, it exploids everywhere T.T

Could anyone give a tutorial or a gulpfile with these plugins installed?

Thank you so much :D

gulpfile.js

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    livereload = require('gulp-livereload'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');

gulp.task('sass', function () {
    gulp.src('public_html/style/scss/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
            cascade: false
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
        .pipe(livereload());
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    livereload.listen(35729);
    gulp.watch('public_html/style/scss/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
});
```

error log from terminal:

```
[22:46:02] Using gulpfile /var/www/satbalma/Gulpfile.js
[22:46:02] Starting 'watch'...
[22:46:03] Finished 'watch' after 357 ms
[22:48:43] Starting 'sass'...
[22:48:43] Finished 'sass' after 22 ms

/var/www/satbalma/node_modules/gulp-autoprefixer/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:157
    this.processing = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                          ^
ReferenceError: Promise is not defined
at LazyResult.async (/var/www/satbalma/node_modules/gulp-autoprefixer/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:157:31)
at LazyResult.then (/var/www/satbalma/node_modules/gulp-autoprefixer/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:79:21)
at DestroyableTransform._transform (/var/www/satbalma/node_modules/gulp-autoprefixer/index.js:24:6)
at DestroyableTransform.Transform._read (/var/www/satbalma/node_modules/gulp-autoprefixer/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:159:10)
at DestroyableTransform.Transform._write (/var/www/satbalma/node_modules/gulp-autoprefixer/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:147:83)
at doWrite (/var/www/satbalma/node_modules/gulp-autoprefixer/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:313:64)
at writeOrBuffer (/var/www/satbalma/node_modules/gulp-autoprefixer/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:302:5)
at DestroyableTransform.Writable.write (/var/www/satbalma/node_modules/gulp-autoprefixer/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:241:11)
at DestroyableTransform.ondata (/var/www/satbalma/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:531:20)
at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:95:17)
```

Comment: can you post your gulp file here? might be a quick fix!

Comment: you must use promise polyfill https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-promise-polyfill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I fixed all problems with ES6-Promise as **[@Unamata Sanatarai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2119863/unamata-sanatarai)** said but gulp didn't reload web when I made changes in all files, only in .scss files.

Now with this code, livereload watch all files in my project:

```
gulp.watch(['app/**/*.*', 'public_html/**/*.*', 'utils/**/*.*']).on('change', function(file) {livereload.changed(file.path);});
```

Where `app/**/*.* ... utils/**/*.*` are my project directories. With this code I skip node_modules and vendor folders (in my case), but you can extend them if needed.

Answer (score 2):

I had this error before.
Add the following to your `package.json`

```
"es6-promise": "~3.1.2",
"es6-promise-polyfill": "~1.2.0",
```

and in your `gulpfile.js` do:

```
var Promise      = require('es6-promise').Promise;
```

should help

Comment: I suppose i need to call npm install promise promise-polyfill --save-dev no?

Comment: Ok, ok it works fine! But, livereload only reloads sass files and I want to reload all files inside my working directory including js scripts, php and so on

Answer (score 0):

You can use plain `autoprefixer` with `gulp-postcss` like so:

```
npm i --save-dev gulp-postcss autoprefixer
```

**gulpfile.js**

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    livereload = require('gulp-livereload'),
    postcss = require('gulp-postcss'),
    autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer')({ browsers: ['last 2 versions'] });

gulp.task('sass', function () {
    gulp.src('public_html/style/scss/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(postcss([autoprefixer]))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
        .pipe(livereload());
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    livereload.listen(35729);
    gulp.watch('public_html/style/scss/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
});
```